# electron, Vuejs app not launched e2e selenium, python

Tags: python, selenium, electron, e2e-testing

I am looking for steps to perform e2e testing using selenium, python for electron app.

1. sample app to create and run in electron, vuejs.

   npm install electron --save-dev
   npm install -g @vue/cli
   vue create new-app
   vue add electron-builder

   launch app to test:

   npm run serve

   npm run electron:serve
2. download chrome driver.
3. create python (py) with following code:

   from selenium import webdriver

   from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

   driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:/Users/ddd/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')

   remote_app = webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver(
   command_executor=f'http://localhost:9515',
   desired_capabilities = {'chromeOptions':{ 'binary':
   'C:/Users/ddd/source/repos/vueselenium/new-app/node_modules/.bin/electron'}},
   browser_profile=None,
   proxy=None,
   keep_alive=False)

   print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
   driver.maximize_window()
   print(driver.title)
   driver.quit()

Not able to launch the electron app from this python file.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Hello i have some info here linking the way that i do it and also the way that others do it: https://medium.com/@chasethesun/how-to-use-python-selenium-to-test-an-electron-app-ffe01f170ddc

You might want to try this method first. Make sure chromedriver.exe is at the same level as this executor file.

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = "/Applications/Electron.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

driver.get("http://www.google.com")


driver.quit()
```